# logical equivalence in predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I was studying discrete mathematics, one of the basic subjects in cs department.

In particular, studying the chapter "Logics", I came to have some trouble.

While solving problem saying

" Let $S(x)$ be the predicate “$x$ is a student”, and $F(x)$ be the predicate
“$x$ is a faculty member,” and $A(x, y)$ be the predicate
“$x$ has asked $y$ a question”, where the domain consists of
all people associated with your school. Use quantifiers to
express each of these statements.

e) There is a faculty member who has never been asked
a question by a student."

Here, I answered like $∃x(F(x) ∧ ∀y(S(y) →
¬A(y,x)))$.

But some of the solutions I got from Google says: $∃x((F(x) ∧ ∀y(S(y)) →
¬A(y,x))$.

The difference here is the positions of the parentheses implicating the range of antecedents(conditions).

The official solution says that one I thought of was right,

but the problem is that when thinking about the meaning of the second statements,

I can find no errors:(

Wouldn't there be any way to know the difference without using operation rules(i.e. implication into negation and disjunction)?

Thank you for reading this long message.

Comment: The second formula $∃x((F(x)∧∀y(S(y))→¬A(y,x))$ is bad parenthesized. Maybe do you mean $∃x \forall y((F(x) \land S(y))→¬A(y,x))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $a \rightarrow b \equiv \neg a \lor b$, then

$ ∃x((F(x) ∧ ∀y(S(y)) → ¬A(y,x)) \equiv ∃x((\neg F(x)
\lor \exists y \neg(S(y)) \lor \neg A(y,x))$

$∃x(F(x) ∧ ∀y(S(y) → ¬A(y,x))) \equiv ∃x(F(x) ∧ ∀y( \neg S(y) \lor ¬A(y,x)))$

Use now universality and existance, and notice that if you make a $\Sigma$ that contain the clauses:

$ ((\neg F(a) \lor \neg(S(b)) \lor \neg A(b,a))$

$(F(a) ∧ \neg S(b) \lor ¬A(b,a))$

$\Sigma_{1} = \{\neg F(a) \lor \neg S(b) \lor \neg A(b,a)\}$

$\Sigma_{2} = \{F(a), \neg S(b) \lor ¬A(b,a)\}$

Notice then the difference of both $\Sigma$, the second one responds to the predicate you said at the beggining

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your clever explanations~